# How to access history objects when cross validating keras wrapper estimators in sklearn?

Tags: scikit-learn, keras

I would like to see the loss/error progression for each split in the cross validation. `keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasClassifier`'s fit method returns a `history` object with the data I want, but it is not accessible when running it in the `sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate` variant methods.

How can I access the history objects for each epoch in each split?

Comment: cross_validate clones the supplied model to fit each fold. So you cant get that. You need to roll your own cross-validation code to see the history for each fold split.

Comment: @Alex Did you ever a find a better way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sklearn pipeline + keras sequential model - how to get history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54358841/sklearn-pipeline-keras-sequential-model-how-to-get-history)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the [CSVLogger](https://keras.io/callbacks/#csvlogger) callback to access the full history. Setting up the CSVLogger callback is easy and it will record: {epoch, acc, loss, val_acc, val_loss} in whatever filename you specify.

In my code, I do something like:

```
keras_classifier.fit(X, y, groups=None, 
    callbacks=[keras.callbacks.CSVLogger(filename, append=True)])
```

Setting `append=True` should ensure that all the data for all splits are included in the file.

Things to consider:

- I'm not sure if this would work with `n_jobs=-1` (for distributing processing over multiple processors), but if you running single-threaded, it should work.
- Be sure to delete the file before running your classifier (or during initialization) to avoid appending to that file indefinitely.