# sklearn pipeline + keras sequential model - how to get history?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, scikit-learn, pipeline

[Keras](https://keras.io) models, when `.fit` is called, return a history object. Is it possible to retrieve it if I use this model as one step of a sklearn pipeline?
btw, i'm using python 3.6

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure if `Pipeline` lets you get the return types of the objects in the pipeline. However, I do think it would be very simple to have the pipeline return the data, then fit the model on the returned data in regular Keras yielding the history object. I know this does not answer your question specifically, but it can lead to just getting the history object easily. If you need help doing that, post your code in an edit.

Comment: thanks, man! was thinking the same. I was just wondering if I would be able to somehow get access to the history object.

Answer (score 5):

The History callback records training metrics for each epoch. This includes the loss and the accuracy (for classification problems) as well as the loss and accuracy for the validation dataset, if one is set.

The history object is returned from calls to the `fit()` function used to train the model. Metrics are stored in a dictionary in the history member of the object returned.

This also means that the values have to be in the scope of the `fit()` function or the sequential model, so if it is in a sklearn pipeline, it doesn't have access to the final values, and it can't store, or return what it can't see.

As of right now I an not aware of a history callback in sklearn so the only I see for you is to manually record the metrics you want to track. One way to do so would be to have pipeline return the data and then simply fit your model onto it. If you are not able to figure that out comment.

Comment: Basically it is about variable scopes.

Comment: Is this still true?